Cookie cutter argument for nonphysicalism
A cookie cutter comes in a variety of shapes. If you see a star-shaped cookie, you may infer, ceteris paribus, we have a star-shaped cookie cutter.
Likewise, what "comes of the mind" are thoughts, ideas, etc. and these have, to some extent, a nonphysical side to them.
May we infer, hence, that at the very least, the mind has a nonphysical aspect to it?

Inferring souls won't do you any good. Physicalists are allowed to believe in souls because 'physical' doesn't actually mean anything.

What if the product is epi and emergent? A mold for transparent plastic doesn't have to be transparent...

@gs No dictionary in the house? Maybe you can find one on the interweb...

Why not just make it a tautology? Thoughts are aspects of the mind, they are, "to some extent", nonphysical, therefore, the mind has nonphysical aspects. This is not only circular, but the vagueness of "aspects" with "extents" makes it also nearly vacuous. A physicalist can easily agree to "nonphysical aspects to some extent" because that is not what they are talking about in "everything supervenes on the physical".

A cookie cutter is not a cookie itself. Just the same shape does not mean the same material

You might infer a cookie cutter, yes, but it could also be that I'm cutting them by hand with a knife.

@KristianBerry, I agree. I'm inferring nonphysicalism from purported nonphysical properties of "mind-stuff".

@gs, there's nothing wrong with souls being physical, but that part of metaphysics will come later I guess.

@DoubleKnot that's true, is the material a "shape"?

@JackAidley, see my response

@tkruse see my response to Doubleknot

It depends on how you define non-physical.
Is energy physical? Is resonance physical? Are quantum states physical? Are ideas written in a book physical? Is a program running on a computer physical?
If you consider none of those physical, then I understand why you might say that the operation of the mind and the products of the mind are non-physical.
I consider all of those physical.  And I believe those and related effects are sufficient to describe the operation of the mind and its "products".
Two different definitions of the word, two different ways of modeling the situation, two different sets of assumptions, hence two different sets of conclusions, each correctly derived within its own space.
I am not convinced that resolving this is within the scope of philosophy. Philosophy is good for exploring what the implications of each might be, but if it hasn't resolved this in several millennia my own conclusion is that it is the wrong tool to address the question.

What is physical. There are 2 things on Wikipedia that are part of the definition of physical, viz. matter & energy.

@Hudjefa so your question then I think is: are patterns of energy also physical? A paper dress pattern is not a dress, but it is physical. But the ideas of the pattern, which someone has copyrighted and can charge royalties for, don't seem physical. If someone can show me how the tune for Happy Birthday can still have royalty protection after 100 years, and how the financial industry is physical, I'll listen. In the meantime, I can't eat a cookie cutter, no matter how hungry I am. And no one even dreams of eating "star-shaped". Would all the stars vanish if they did?

@ScottRowe Actually, as of 2016 Happy Birthday was determined to be in the public domain retroactively back to the point where it should've naturally passed into it.

@ScottRowe: I think I could argue that those are based in the physical. But I don't think it would convince anyone who prefers the other model, and I don't think consensus is needed as long as we understand what each other is saying.

@keshlam so this seems like one of those issues where the problem arises when someone says that a problem has arisen, and if everyone just overlooks it, there's no problem. True for so many things in modern life... We could stop bringing up race, gender, religion, and everyone simply mind their own business. Would that work for Philosophy? Hmm.

@ScottRowe: I didn't say drop discussing it. In fact I said explicitly that exploring the implications of each approach seems to be a good topic for philosophy. What I did say was that both approaches seem to be valid within their defined spaces and I don't believe that trying to resolve either/or will be as productive as considering both/and. If you feel otherwise, go for it and good luck to you.

Sorry. I didn't mean to 'reduce' your statement to a single position. I guess I tend to be a closet reductionist. Engineering forces me to make 'good' choices and abandon endless dithering and the search for the 'best' choice. Get the program running right and move on. Perhaps it comes out of a lifetime of having to tackle really hard problems (in all kinds of areas) alone: there was no debate, and no extra time for investigation. So my 'philosophy' is Do It Yourself. And don't blame or deflect.

@ScottRowe: No problem. Most of us are human , and I'm an engineer myself.

"I consider all of those physical. And I believe those and related effects are sufficient to describe the operation of the mind and its "products"." - that is opinion though. Whether one considers energy as (non-)physical doesn't preclude opinion about consciousness being physical or non-physical. Although the sole concept of something being non-physical already proves that there are non-physical "things". If you believe the idea of non-physical does not exist in the physical world, then it itself is non-physical.

You're welcome to that opinion. I find it unconvincing and circular, but as I said it depends on what your core assumptions are.

Are ideas written in a book physical? Is a program running on a computer physical? - I wouldn't consider these physical. Otherwise, I would have to accept that God is physical, since it definitely exists in human minds, books, and more sacrifices and crimes are committed in his name than in the name of physics.

I would distinguish between ideas, beliefs, information, and other abstract notions vs. how these are physically recorded/communicated. At least, this is how I see materialism: the material world is primary, and the ideas exist in this world. (But perhaps this is marxist influence.)

@RogerV.: (fixing typo) Man's ideas of God are certainly man's, and by my usage as much of the physical world as language or music or science or other human patterns of behavior. That's completely orthogonal to whether those ideas are even vaguely correct. Religion is physical in this model. After all, given the conflicting descriptions, at least one religion is at least partly wrong, and that part certainly isn't part of god; proceed by induction

If you rotate the starshaped cookie 90 degrees, that is, you see it from the side, you will see an elongated rectangle instead of a star. You could now infer that the non-physical, an idea or a thought, also has a physical side...

Great answer! I guess I should say my argument only suggests nonphysicalism as (merely?) a *component.

When interpreting “the mind” as the “set of mental processes” I read your final question as:

Do mental processes have a non-physical aspect?

Yes, they have content and meaning, because the set of all mental processes is the information processing of the brain of the organism. Content and meaning are obvious for conscious mental processes. For non-conscious mental processes it is a nearby hypothesis.
Caveat: The non-physical aspect of mental processes is not enough to support non-physicalism, understood as the opposition of physicalism. In the context of mental processes this dichotomy is questionable.

It's just a thought that crossed my mind. I have no idea if the argument holds any water. I've treated the brain/mind (?) as some kinda stuff-processor. If the stuff is nonphysical then is there a nonphysical aspect to the processor (mind/brain)? Someone mentioned the interaction problem

If you take as premises :

that "thoughts, ideas, etc. ... have, to some extent, a nonphysical side to them," and
that these things are "of the mind,"

then yes, you can conclude that the mind has nonphysical aspects to it: the things of the mind that you accept as a premise to have non-physical sides to them.

Yes, are ideas, thoughts, noema in general, nonohysical. It's not every day that you hear someone say (for example) that atheism weighs 2 kg. This is probably a naïve conception of physicalism, which has a reductive avatar.

This is one of the core debates of philosophy of mind. SEP has a good article here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/
A working definition of "physical" is anything that interacts within our world - otherwise, how would we know it's there? However, interactive dualists would argue with this definition since "mental substance" interacts with matter/energy.
Potential examples of non-physical things are abstract ideas like mathematics and supernatural entities like souls etc.
However, even for things like mathematics, one can argue that concepts supervene on the physical -- they get their existence via being instantiated as information in some physical system. So, things like the Peano Axioms would literally disappear if Earth and the Voyager satellites were wiped out (and any outbound signals were garbled). Platonists will disagree with this.
The nature of this supervenience is also up for debate: is it emergence (physicalism) or transmission (e.g., William James thought the brain was a transmitter/receiver of the soul)?

The Hard Problem returns....
Until we understand why there is subjectivity we're going to have this gap that we will fill with untestable things.
Is there a non-physical part to mind? It's hard to say right now. Those who are frustrated by Physicalism or see a fundamental flaw in it will go with "non-physical" of some sort. I am more sanguine about Physicalism's prospects, especially the new approaches looking at information vs just matter and energy. As I've posted elsewhere, information may lead to a viable form of neutral monism that has both objective/functional and subjective aspects.
Information theory is relatively young field, and neurobiological information theory is very young. We have some interesting ideas such as Tononi's Integrated Information Theory but nothing near definitive and tested.
My current view is that the mind/body distinction is the result of how our brain partitions information to survive in the world - it creates the subject-object distinction. However, there will likely be no E=MC^2 of consciousness because subjectivity in itself is not a functional property, which is why it seems epiphenomenal to many (not to be confused with the processes we associate with consciousness, which are clearly causally relevant).
But why a subjective aspect at all (i.e., the hard problem again)? My own speculative theory is that the foundation of reality is information, which exists as brute awareness representing that information (what I will call a "locus"). This is what reality actually is - a complex web of loci interacting with other loci. So, it's not "Why do material things possess mind?" But how do mind and matter emerge from information?
To me, "what exists right now" amounts to "what loci are present right now." It's not atoms, quarks, etc or "spin networks" etc. So how can we define these loci if they are a bedrock concept? My take is that a fundamental property of awareness is unity - it is an experience by necessity since it defines a subject -- if there were more experiences than one, then we'd have multiple subjects and multiple loci.
Therefore, I look to what could provide this kind of "metaphysical binding" and quantum information theory fits the bill. It needs to be quantum because we will rely on entanglement as the "metaphysical glue" that picks out "this is a thing" from "this is a collection of things" -- I like to call this "fundamental ontology" vs "conventional ontology" -- the former is truly invisible, the latter (e.g., clouds, brains, planets, atoms) are collections of these things but we treat them linguistically as a thing (by convention).
We also need the discreteness/quantum part to help "pinch off" distinct loci/subjects - the universe appears to consist in innumerable, ephemeral "views".
Under this, two loci are distinct if they have different quantum information bases.
Anyway, probably way too much on my little crackpot theory, but TL;DR; is that I don't see an advantage to trying to call the mental "non-physical" as it begs a lot of questions about interaction with "the physical". I'd be more inclined to expand what we consider "physical" since if we ever discovered "mind stuff" and could measure it then we would have effectively physicalized it :)
If you want a similar persepctive from an academic, here is a nice little paper

I don't kmow if this is apropos, but  the approach to the nonphysical via the physical seems to be quantum physics. Is there a subjective component to QM?

@Hudjefa I mean that is my view in that it has the has the right properties to serve as the physical basis for a "subject". I think QM is definitely getting at somethig fundamental but I don't want to say that mind == QM - I'm more neutral monist in that regard.

These questions at our current level of philosophical understanding do not have a definitive answer.
Physicalists, who are inspired by the huge success of physics, assume that all processes and beings in nature are physical in nature. This is an assumption. They are one species of materialists.
Dualists assume both the existence of a nonphysical mental world and physical natural world but how they interact with each other, as they must, is still a question mired in controversy. One answer is that they supervene on some third substance, Spinoza took that to be a mode of the divine - which is neither mental nor physical.
Your argument is as good as any to plausibly argue for the nonphysicality of the mental world. Though some will probably say it is obvious by introspection.

You're welcome to introduce a third/fourth/fifth substance. Thanks for the compliment. It's just that I "feel" mental stuff like ideas/thoughts have a nonphysical flavor to them.

@Hudjefa: You're welcome. Spinoza actually posited an infinite number of divine modes, only two of which are accessible to mere mortals, extension and thought. Your "feel" is partly what I meant by saying that nonphysicality "is obvious by introspection".
